# jQuery - Not this or prev or next?

Tags: jquery

How can I select all divs of a class except 'this', and also not the next and previous div? The code below selects everything except for 'this':

```
$(".image-div").not(this).each(function() {
            $(this).animate({
                    width: '250px'
                }, 500, function() {
                // Animation complete.
            });
        }   
    });
```

Thanks

UPDATE - Here is my full code:

```
$(".image-div").click(function () {


    if ($(this).css('width') != '500px') {

        $(this).animate({
            width: '500px'
            }, 500, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });

        $(this).prev().animate({
            width: '125px'
            }, 500, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });

        $(this).next().animate({
            width: '125px'
            }, 500, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });


    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '250px'
            }, 500, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    }


    $(".image-div").not(this).each(function() {
            $(this).animate({
                    width: '250px'
                }, 500, function() {
                // Animation complete.
            });

    });


});
```

All div.image-div's start out 250px wide. I need it so when you click on a div, it expands to 500px and its neighbors on both sides (also div.image-div's) shrink to 125px.

When you click on the div again it and its neighbors re-size to 250px. Also if you click on another div, all the divs (except for the clicked on div and its neighbors) re-size to 250px.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your HTML so that we can see what you're trying to do?

Comment: yep . please provide some code please

Comment: I will do if necessary, but ive simplified the task so I can understand whats going on. As 'this', 'prev' and 'next' are all standard selectors in jQuery, can you not select them all (or exclude them all from a selection) in one go? Thanks

Comment: you can try adding this after the .not method .prevAll('selector') im not quite sure if it will work but its worth the try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it a little bit for my own understanding, but you should be able to figure it out. It's sloppy, but it works.

```
var divClicked = $(this);

$(".image-div").not(divClicked).not($(".image-div").next()).not($(".image-div").prev()).each(function() {
       $(this).css({
             background: 'blue'
       });

});
```

Comment: Your code seems to select all divs on the page. Ive played around with it but I cant get it working.

Comment: i hadn't understood your question completely until you put the full code up. I was wondering what the meaning of `this` was. But now I get it. Check my edit and see if that's better.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".image-div").click(function() {
            $(".imagediv").not($(this)).not($(this).next()).not($(this).prev()).animate({
                    width: '+=250px'
                }, 500);
        });
```